# Assigning EditTextPreference inputType "number"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm a long time user of stackoverflow, first time asking a question. I hope you can help me.

As a new android programmer, I have this problem.

I am not sure what data type to use with EditTextPreference inputType "number".

If inputType is "text", then I would use this code (and it works.)

```
SharedPreferences getCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
         final **String** customCode = getCode.**getString**("code", "sometext");
```

and I would check the EditText like this:

```
if (body.equalsIgnoreCase(customCode)) {
    DO SOMETHING
}
```

That works for text!

What to do if inputType is number? What data type to use and how to convert it in String?

I hope you understand what I am trying to say, thanks

Comment: I am not understanding the question, what is "body"? what would you do with EditText? do you want to set a integer like text in the editText?

Comment: In xml use  input type =number

Comment: i think u wants to ask which type of datatype used when edittext input type is number please specify what u exactly wants

Comment: I _think_ he wants to know what kind of data type is returned from `EditTextPreference` `getText`. The answer is `String`, and he can convert it to `int` if he wants, using the standard Java API. He is probably confused because, in his mind, he is expecting the data type to change depending on the input mask applied, which is not the case.

Comment: yes i got that so @xsonz do not worry about the data type go for String data type and convert it whereever u want by simple converting method of the java api

Comment: The thing is, I didn't even know how to ask a question..but you guys got it right.

I thought I can't use a string because "numbers" are..well, numbers. But as it turns out, it doesn't matter. the code I posted above is accurate, all I had to do is change inputType to "numbers".

Comment: yes @xsonz you got it right

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
//To save
SharedPreferences getCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getcode.edit();
editor.putInt("code",integer_value);
editor.commit();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences getcode= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
int value = getcode.getInt("code", 0); //0 is the default value
```